# C++11 is it possible to construct an std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++11, initializer-list

I have a class that's using an `std::discrete_distribution` which can take an `std::initializer_list` OR a couple of iterators. My class is in some ways wrapping the `discrete_distribution` so I really wanted to mimic the ability to take an `std::initializer_list` which would then be passed down.

This is simple.

However, the `std::initializer_list` will always be constructed through some unknown values. So, if it was just a `std::discrete_distribution` I would just construct from iterators of some container. However, for me to make that available via my class, I would need to templatize the class for the Iterator type.

I don't want to template my class because it's only occasionally that it would use the `initializer_list`, and the cases where it doesn't, it uses an `std::uniform_int_distribution` which would make this template argument, maybe confusing.

I know I can default the template argument, and I know that I could just define only `vector::iterator`s if I wanted; I'd just rather not.

Comment: I guess `std::uniform_distribution_list` is a typo, and got no idea what you really meant to write.

Comment: I did answer, but you should have given some code in your question; that would have made it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) cannot be non-empty constructed in standard C++. BTW, it is the same for C [stdarg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html) `va_list` (and probably for similar reasons, because variadic function argument passing is implementation specific and generally has its own [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) peculiarities; see however [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/)).

In [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), `std::initializer_list` is somehow *known* to the C++ compiler (likewise `<stdarg.h>` uses some builtin things from the C compiler), and has special support.

The C++11 standard (more exactly its [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) draft, which is almost exactly the same) says in §18.9.1 that `std::initializer_list` has only an empty constructor and refers to §8.5.4 *list-initialization*

You probably should use `std::vector` and its iterators in your case.

As a rule of thumb and intuitively, `std::initializer_list` is useful for *compile-time* known argument lists, and if you want to handle *run-time* known arguments (with the "number" of "arguments" unknown at compile time) you should provide a constructor for that case (either taking some iterators, or some container, as arguments).

If your class has a constructor accepting `std::initializer_list<int>` it probably should have another constructor accepting `std::vector<int>` or `std::list<int>` (or perhaps `std::set<int>` if you have some commutativity), then you don't need some weird templates on iterators. BTW, if you want iterators, you would templatize the constructor, not the entire class.